# Как сохранить новые поля в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

Я создал класс который расширяет набор свойств Entity Framework.

Модель:

```
public class Student : IdentityUser
{
     public Student() : base() { }

     public string FirstName{get; set;}

}
```

cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
   <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
</div>



public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var firstName = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
    if (Input.FirstName != firstName)
    {
        var setFirstNameResult = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        if (!setFirstNameResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting firstName for user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }
    }
```

Метод `_userManager.UpdateAsync(user);` не обновляет модель, после перезагрузки поле опять пустое и в базу данных оно  не записываеться.

Подскажите где я ошибся?

Comment: Identity не занимается сохранением данных, это задача слоя хранения. Если вы используете Entity Framework - попробуйте поискать ответ на вопрос *"как сохранить новые поля в Entity Framework"*.

Comment: вам нужен не дефолтный usermanager<IdentityUser> - а UserManager<Student>

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Comment: @AK  Я использую UserManager<Student>, проблема именно в методе _userManager.UpdateAsync(user); Например для сохранения емейла есть метод _userManager.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email);  я предполагал, что сохраняя всю модель, будет обновляться и новое поле, но что-то видимо не так.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно сначала вам нужен принимать миграции база данных.
Проста в Package Manager Console запишите 
   **add-migration Initial** потом
   **update-database**

Comment: Я сделал это, иначе у меня была бы ошибка записи в BD